# Laravel chunk() mistaken with array_chunk?

Tags: php, laravel-5, chunks

I'm working on a local project with Laravel 5. I'm trying to grab what could potentially be (or become) huge amounts of data. I'm doing so

```
    $tickets = Ticket::getResolvedTicketsBetween($start,$end)->chunk(200, function($chunkOfTickets){
    foreach ($chunkOfTickets as $ticket) {
        echo $ticket->id;
    }
});
```

The problem is I'm getting the error

```
array_chunk() expects parameter 3 to be boolean, object given
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help me, I'm following the documentation accordingly... I think...

Comment: what is the `getResolvedTicketsBetween` method returning? A collection? A query?

Comment: that function is actually one line. return Ticket::where('created_at', '>=', $start)->where('created_at', '<=', $end)->where('state','=','Resolved')->get();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a search of the Laravel framework and the only usage is in the `Collection` class, which has a `chunk()` function not to be confused with the `chunk()` function of the query builder class.

- http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html
- http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html

If `getResolvedTicketsBetween()` makes a call to `get()` then it will end up returning a **Collection**. If you want to be able to continue building on the query, remove the call to `get()`.

My guess at how your code might look:

```
function getResolvedTicketsBetween($start, $end) {

    // Dont do this
    // return Ticket::where('created_at', '>=', $start)->where('created_at', '<=', $end)->where('state','=','Resolved')->get()

    // Do this instead (returns Query Builder instance)
    return Ticket::where('created_at', '>=', $start)->where('created_at', '<=', $end)->where('state','=','Resolved');
}
```

Comment: AHHH! ok, I get it. It was the get(). With that error I don't think I would've ever figured it out on my own. Many thanks.

Comment: No problem. Whenever I run into issues with Laravel, I dive into the framework code and see what is going on. It helps so much. `vendor/laravel/framework/src` is your friend.

Comment: On a slightly side question. I can call a function inside the for each like $ticket->updateValue(); and then reffer to that ticket inside the module as $this right?

Comment: I wanted to check the framework code, my phpStorm is acting out it won't let me ctrl click the functions and jump to the code... :/

Comment: Another helpful tip in debugging is the use of a library that displays **everything** - I like [Kint](https://packagist.org/packages/raveren/kint). Dump an object to your browser with `\Kint::dump($object)` and you can navigate through a ridiculous amount of information about that object. I often use it to see what classes I'm getting back from the framework.

Comment: @Thaenor No, I don't think you can use `$this` to reference the object in the loop. In Javascript that works due to the way scopes are, but in PHP it will be a reference to the class instance your code is inside. If not a class instance or if a static method, then `$this` will not work at all.

Comment: @cillosis I can see that. Debugging it with kint just realized those objects were null. I'll need to pass the ticket as a parameter.

Comment: I'm doing $ticket->updateTicketPoints($ticket); inside the for each. At this point I should be on a ticket by ticket analysis. However referencing the $ticket inside the model and using Kint's dump it's printing out two different objects? How is this happening?

Comment: I'm not sure, never used kint.

Comment: it's not because of kint. For some reason php is handling "a single ticket" as two tickets. But the code seems to be working (it was written to handle only one ticket at a time). maybe it's some Laravel engine optimization or something.

Comment: I think I got it why this is happening. Does Laravel's chunk run in parallel? Maybe I'm multi-processing two array elements at the same time. @cillosis - PS: Sorry for the spam

Comment: @Thaenor No, its not parallel. It has a while loop and grabs chunks of records and passes each chunk to your callback. If you `dd($ticket);` is it an instance of your **Ticket** model? (it should be). You can reference the code here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1486

Comment: @cillosis dd($ticket); returns the data for a single ticket. however var_dump($ticket); prints the data of two tickets... no idea why.